Виртуализация данных в таблице
У кого-нибудь был опыт виртуализации данных в таблице Table (из antd) для динамической подгрузки данных по скроллу? Например, с помощью react-window или tanstack/react-virtual? Никак не получается подвязать к таблице(
Попробовала с react-window, но она не работает с таблицами (только со списками).

Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.
